# net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR y Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error ¿Debo tener un certificado para corregirlo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ssl, https

Estoy haciendo una red social, la primera pagina se muestra perfectamente que es un formulario para llenar datos ya sea para registrarse o para iniciar sesión lo cual tiene como puerto el localhost:3000, pero el problema ocurre que a darle al botón de registrarse o iniciar sesión es donde aparecen esos dos errores y no me dirige a ninguna pagina manteniendose en el formulario.

El puerto por supuesto está en https por si las dudas de que quizas el error sea porque es http. También he intentado resolver el problema como la mayoría aconsejan: cambiar el horario, borrar historial, caché, cookies, borrar estado SSL, desactivar extensiones, antivirus, desconectar protocolo Quic, etc... nada funcionó.

Este es el archivo de autentificación del lado del cliente, en la linea 31 está en https como mencioné:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import axios from 'axios';

import signinImage from '../assets/signup.jpg';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const initialState = {
    fullName: '',
    username: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    avatarURL: '',
}

const Auth = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState(initialState);
    const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(true);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setForm({ ...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { username, password, phoneNumber, avatarURL } = form;

        const URL = 'https://localhost:5000/auth';

        const { data: { token, userId, hashedPassword, fullName } } = await axios.post(`${URL}/${isSignup ? 'signup' : 'login'}`, {
            username, password, fullName: form.fullName, phoneNumber, avatarURL,
        });

        cookies.set('token', token);
        cookies.set('username', username);
        cookies.set('fullName', fullName);
        cookies.set('userId', userId);

        if(isSignup) {
            cookies.set('phoneNumber', phoneNumber);
            cookies.set('avatarURL', avatarURL);
            cookies.set('hashedPassword', hashedPassword);
        }

        window.location.reload();
    }

    const switchMode = () => {
        setIsSignup((prevIsSignup) => !prevIsSignup);
    }

    return (
        <div className="auth__form-container">
            <div className="auth__form-container_fields">
                <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content">
                    <p>{isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In'}</p>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="fullName">Full Name</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="fullName" 
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Full Name"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}
                        <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="username" 
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Username"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="phoneNumber" 
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Phone Number"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}
                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="avatarURL">Avatar URL</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="avatarURL" 
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Avatar URL"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}
                        <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="password" 
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder="Password"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="confirmPassword" 
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                            )}
                        <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_button">
                            <button>{isSignup ? "Sign Up" : "Sign In"}</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div className="auth__form-container_fields-account">
                        <p>
                            {isSignup
                             ? "Already have an account?" 
                             : "Don't have an account?"
                             }
                             <span onClick={switchMode}>
                             {isSignup ? 'Sign In' : 'Sign Up'}
                             </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div className="auth__form-container_image">
                <img src={signinImage} alt="sign in" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Auth
```

Y este es el índice por parte del servidor, que de nuevo pongo que el puerto está en el 5000 como en el archivo de autentificación:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth.js");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

require('dotenv').config();

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const messagingServiceSid = process.env.TWILIO_MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID;
const twilioClient = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, World!');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { message, user: sender, type, members } = req.body;

if(type === 'message.new') {
    members
        .filter((member) => member.user_id !== sender.id)
        .forEach(({ user }) => {
            if(!user.online) {
                twilioClient.messages.create({
                    body: `You have a new message from ${message.user.fullName} - ${message.text}`,
                    messagingServiceSid: messagingServiceSid,
                    to: user.phoneNumber
                })
                    .then(() => console.log('Message sent!'))
                    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
            }
        })

        return res.status(200).send('Message sent!');
}

return res.status(200).send('Not a new message request');
});

app.use('/auth', authRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un certificado SSL para tu sitio? Las solicitudes `https` validan la autenticidad de la conexión mediante dicho certificado. Lo usual es que tu servidor web (Apache, nginx, IIS, etc.) sea el encargado de administrar lo relativo al dominio y certificado y que tu aplicación NodeJS se encuentre detrás de dicho servidor y sea accedida mediante un Proxy Reverso y no directamente desde la web.

Comment: @MauricioContreras No tengo un certificado. En ese caso entonces mi unica opcion sería tener el certificado para poder correrlo? O existen otras alternativas?

Comment: Para realizar solicitudes `https` necesitas un certificado. Podrías hacer tu aplicación usando solicitudes `http` que no necesitan de un certificado.